# how to remove cover on risen bread dough?

Tags: bread

how does one remove the cover on the 2nd bread dough rise without disturbing the rise?  My bread tends to fall even after a beautiful rise.

Comment: Can you show us what you mean? Do you mean the "final rise" before the bread goes into the oven or a true second rise before the bread gets shaped? Are you oiling the top of your bread? What are you covering it with? Please give us more information.

Comment: Is this cover sticking? If so you need to use a bigger bowl

Answer (score 1):

Is this a second rise in the bowl?  Make sure the bowl is tall enough so the risen dough won't reach the rim.  You have to punch it down before shaping anyway...  If this is the rise after shaping, you don't need to cover the dough.